# Using 20 Servos at once, with raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, servomotor, rcservo

I have recently been asked to review a raspberry pi hat (from a programming view) that will allow PWM control of upto 16 servos, however I am hoping to use this time to work on a hexapod idea I have been thinking about for a while, which requires a minimum of 18 servo's, and preferably 20 (camera/sensor pan and tilt).

My question is:

What is a relatively cheap and uncomplicated way of extending my control over those extra 4 servo's?

It would appear most servo controller hat/shiels for arduino and raspi are upto 16 servos, and can be extended by buying another shield, are there any other options?

Any advice in this subject would be greatly appreciated, preferably dumbed down a bit, and I don't know a great deal about micro controller hardware (more of a software guy)

Comment: I imagine using a hat will result in cleaner wiring, but you might instead consider using 3 ea. 8-servo boards, eg like [Pololu #207](https://www.pololu.com/product/207) or a 16-servo hat plus a #207

Comment: Pololu also makes the [maestro](https://www.pololu.com/product/1356) that can control as many as 24 servos.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the maestro series looks pretty promising, now to choose between the 24 and 18, how much do I really want pan and tilt

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like the adafruit [Adafruit 16-Channel PWM / Servo HAT for Raspberry Pi](http://www.adafruit.com/product/2327) You can stack as many as you want to get as many outputs as you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however in my question I did mention that I've seen the 16 controller shields that can be stacked by buying another, but was looking for other options.

Comment: The problem is that the most common pwm controllers have 16 outputs, if you are looking for something even less expensive you could go with something like [this](http://www.adafruit.com/products/815) it can be daisy chained.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the PCA9685 16-channel PWM controller (12-bit and I2C) that will set you back about €2.10 when ordered on ebay. It uses i2c and you can chain up to 64 of these controllers. So you will need only two of them probably. You just need a few pins to connect them to either a raspberry or an arduino. The module itself has a small form-factor. Software support is also great: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_PCA9685. I did learn also about the adafruit solution, but I'm glad the price has made me look a bit further.